# Best practice for multiple classes inside module that need different imports?

Tags: python

I see in PEP8 that the accepted best practice for importing is to put all imports at the top of the module. I am wondering if this is still the case if you want to have multiple subclasses with different import needs all inside the same module.

Specifically, I am making a generic `DataConnector` class to read data from different sources and then put that data into a pandas dataframe. I will have subclasses that read the different sources of data. For instance, one subclass will be `CsvConnector(DataConnector)`, another `PGdatabaseConnector(DataConnector)`. The Csv subclass will need to import `csv` and the PGdatabase class will need to import `psycopg2`. Is the best practice still to keep all the imports at the top of the entire module?

(Logically it seem that all the classes should be contained in one module, but I could also see putting them all in different modules and then I wouldn't have to worry about importing libraries that wouldn't be used.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are occasional cases where you'd want to put imports elsewhere (such as when imports have side-effects that you need to invoke in a certain order), but in this case, all your imports should go at the top of the .py source file like a table of contents. If you feel like your file is getting too cluttered, break out each class and the relevant imports into new source files.

Comment: except when you want your application to still partially run if only some of the modules are available. I think the OP wants to be able conditionally import per class in the same module (remember, Python is not Java, you can have multiple classes in same module).